# Can't detect corners with Harris detection

Tags: c#, emgucv

I want to detect corners with Harris detection in Emgu CV but the result is always black with different images.

my code :

```cs
Image<Gray, byte> img;
Image<Gray, float> m_CornerImage;
Image<Gray, byte> m_ThresholdImage;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        img = new Image<Gray, byte>(opf.FileName);
        imageBox1.Image = img;
    }
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create corner strength image and do Harris
    m_CornerImage = new Image<Gray, float>(img.Size);
    CvInvoke.CornerHarris(img, m_CornerImage, 3, 3, 0.01);

    // create and show inverted threshold image
    m_ThresholdImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(img.Size);
    CvInvoke.Threshold(m_CornerImage, m_ThresholdImage, 0.0001,
        255.0, ThresholdType.BinaryInv);

    imageBox3.Image = m_ThresholdImage;
}
```

where is wrong part ??!
thanks :)

Comment: What is `imageBox1`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ this image box is to showing the image after i select it from open file dialog

Comment: Is it a `PictureBox`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ no it is tool in EmguCv for displaying images , it is like PictureBox but it is not in tool box in vs

Comment: i can use picture box but with image box tool i can display image without convert the image to Bitmap (i must covert it with PictureBox )